# Highstock get detailed info when data is grouped

Tags: highcharts

In the click event "this.x" is the first point in the data group.

dataGrouping occurs when you play with the scroll, for example if select show all data, each point represent a week but you have information about every day, so in this point is represented info of all week instead of each day.

¿how I can get the last point in the data group clicked? ¿Hoy can I get the last point represented in this group (in this week)? (week is an example when you play with the scroll grouped data can happen in non common intervals)

```
            plotOptions : {
                series : {
                    point : {
                        events : {
                            click : function(event) {
                                alert(this.x + '  ' + this.y);
                                //HERE?
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JorgeDuenasLerin/QA2Qa/13/

Comment: Wherever you click, that's what data appears in the alert window. It is not always the first, and can be the last.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem comes when you have dataqGrouping. I have modify the question to clarify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After deep testing and several implementations and reimplementations... the conclusion.

You can access to the points variable. It is the solution because it always has the points draw in the screen and you can access it with no change when dataGrouping occurs.

```
var point = event.point;
var points = event.point.series.points;
var index = points.indexOf(point);
var index_next = index+1;
```

Here a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/JorgeDuenasLerin/QA2Qa/88/

You can not work with series.data variable because it change depending on cropThreshold and number of data.

```
series.data
```

here doc:
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series::data

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to get it, but here is what you can do:

- you have `this.x` value, now loop through `this.series.options.data` and compare x-value with your `this.x`
- last object from that comparison (`this.x > this.series.options.data[index][0]`)will be point you are looking for

Comment: Your answer seems that give me the point just before this.x, I can wort it a little more and try to get the next point and iterate over the data to get the point before the next point. (dificult to explain in text).

The problem is that is not practical iterate over 300.000 register each time that I need to get the extremes of a dataGroup.

Comment: You have access to `this.series.currentDataGrouping` and there is some more information about used dataGrouping, maybe something will help you to get better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the series data in the click event by using `this.series`

```
               events: {
                    click: function (event) {
                        var last = this.series.data[this.series.data.length - 1];
                        alert(last.x + ' ' + last.y);
                    }
                }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/38FmW/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem comes when you have dataqGrouping, i do not want the last point in the serie, I want the last point in the group. I have edited my question to clarify it.

Comment: @JDL You might want to update your fiddle to have grouped data, since as it is, it doesn't illustrate the problem

Comment: You are right, I have updated the jsfiddle to show all data, so dataGrouping occurs when you open the jsfiddle by default. Thanks for the advice.